# When ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT changed to anything but "Development" - Blazor app doesn't see resources from razor class libraries when debugged in VS

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Maybe just try the example:

https://github.com/HTD/BlazorProfiles

This is a demo Blazor application (default).
I created 2 custom application profiles: Development and Production.
Both should be debuggable just with pressing F5 key in Visual Studio.

Then I created a dummy Razor Component Library and named it RCL.
I made it a dependency for the main project.
Inside my dummy RCL, within `wwwroot` directory I added `extra.css` file.
The role of that file is to change the background color to light green.
If it happens - it means the file has been loaded. If the background remains gray / white, it is not loaded.

Here's the `_Host.cshtml` fragment loading the CSS:

```html
<link href="_content/RCL/extra.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Try to run it. It works. However on one condition:
`ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable MUST be set to "Development".

If you test the `Production` profile (or change the environment variable to "Production") and then run the application - the `extra.css` file will not be loaded.

[image]

The background doesn't change to green, so something is wrong.
Why does it happen? Is it a bug in Visual Studio?

If you wonder why do I need to set this environment variable: it allows loading of additional

`appsettings.[ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT].json`

file. So I can have different configurations for my app. I need to test my app with different configurations. Now I can only debug it in Visual Studio with "Development" configuration. When I change configuration to anything else I can't run my app because it can't load necessary JavaScript files required by components from the library.

So, expected behavior: no matter what I put into "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" - the files from RCL should always load. Why shouldn't they?

Actual behavior: using different configurations (profiles) breaks Razor Component Library loading.

Comment: This is an interesting bug. I did the same with another opensource project https://github.com/Blazored/Typeahead and the css and js did not load when env was not Development.

Comment: Reproduced. I tried to switch from Kestrel to IIS, but no difference. So it's in the middleware routing manager.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found it [in the ASP.NET core github issues](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/28174). It's actually mentioned [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#create-an-rcl-with-static-assets).

You need to enable static web assets in the webhost:

```
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => {
                webBuilder.UseStaticWebAssets(); // <----
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

edit: note the comment in the Docs

> Calling UseStaticWebAssets isn't required when running an app from published output (dotnet publish).

Answer (score 5):

This had me baffled for a few hours today til I came across the accepted answer, which led me to the docs. For a `NET 6.0` app things have changed slightly:

> ...static web assets are enabled by default in the Development
> environment. To support assets in other environments when running from
> build output, call UseStaticWebAssets on the host builder in
> `Program.cs`:

```
builder.WebHost.UseWebRoot("wwwroot");
builder.WebHost.UseStaticWebAssets();
```

You then also need to call

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

further down after the `app` has been built from `var app = builder.Build();`

Comment: Actually, I did exactly what you suggested but unfortunately, it didn't work.

Comment: Dunno what to tell you, are you using NET 6.0? Check out the docs here for NET 6.0, I basically quoted the relevant part - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#create-an-rcl-with-static-assets

Comment: This works on Net7.0 too.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in NET 8.0 Blazor, the solution is similar to that given for [jhbonarius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6717178/jhbonarius). but because the change can be done in program.cs different line is needed:

```
builder.WebHost.UseStaticWebAssets();
```